# When using sed regex, is there a way of using punctuation in search term without actually changing it during substitution

Tags: text-processing, sed

Say I want to substitute XOrg[ ,.;] to X-Org[while keeping the punctuation intact]. So XOrg, would give X-Org, and 'XOrg ' would give 'X-Org ' etc..

Is there anyway of doing this with sed in the linux terminal?

Right now I can do

```
  sed -r 's/XOrg[ ,.;]/X-Org/g'
```

but here I have to choose which punctuation comes out at the other end. How do I tell it keep the same punctuations it finds?

Comment: you could group it with ()'s and refer back to it; but let me ask: why are you including it? Could you omit it from the search, or do you need it to "anchor" the XOrg text? In other words, is there "XOrg" text that you do *not* want to replace?

Comment: Maybe that wasn't a good example. I'm basically writing a script that's reformatting text before it going insto a tts engine using sed. Some words like acronyms such as prof will be pronounced as prof by the engine which sounds weird. So I need to use sed to replace the prof by professor before the text goes into the tts engine. The thing is, if I use a straight sed 'g/prof/Professor/I' to replace prof with professor, I will have problems if the text contains the full word professor since it has the syllable prof nested within it.

Comment: So sed 'g/prof/Professor/I' of prof will give professor but sed 'g/prof/Professor/I' of Professor will give Professoressor. To avoid this awkward situation, I have to delimate prof with spaces in sed: so I have to use sed 'g/ prof / Professor /I' instead of sed 'g/prof/Professor/I'. This introduces the added complexity of needing to account for every type of punctuation and parenthenses: I'll have to write a seperate sed statement for ' prof,', ' prof ', ' prof.', ' prof;', '(prof ', ' prof)' and '(prof)'.

Comment: I'm trying to see if there is a way of just doing sed -r 's/[ (]prof[ ,.;)]/[keep space or punctutation]professor[keep space or punctutation]/I'

Comment: Are you using a GNU sed? \< and \> may be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found the answer here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4a I'm going to put it up.

Comment: This is harder than you think, especially if you want to take the case where the abbreviation occurs at the end of a sentence and/or line.

Comment: My sript has a lexicon which deals with abbreviations before this step.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4a

To delimate a search term by a range of characters such as punctuations and spaces and have those characters carry through to output instead of being replaced, you the following synthax:

```
    sed -r 's/([group1])term([group2])/\1output\2/g'
```

where ([groupx]) can be ([ ,.;)(]) or ([[:punct:] ]).

Ex.

```
   echo dep\!|sed -r 's/dep([ ,.;)!])/dependency\1/'
```

will give: dep! -> dependency!

```
  echo ' dep,'|sed -r 's/([[:punct:] ])dep([[:punct:] ])/\1dependency\2/'
```

will give ' dep,' -> ' dependency,'